# Code editor (IDE) for CSOM developement - Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, client-object-model, csom, jsom

I am searching for a code editor with which I can connect to SharePoint library, like I can open a complete library in the editor, edit, save changes, which will be reflected in the library.

Normally I would checkout the file to edit, click on open with explorer option and edit the file in Notepad++ or sublime editor. I am looking for that open with explorer option to be synced with the editor.

Is there any editor that comes with addons to work with SharePoint? Right now, I am using sublime to write my javascript code, Also I use Github's Atom, brackets etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map SharePoint library/site as a Network Drive. Now use Windows Explorer to browse file and open with your favourite editor.

From my knowledge only SharePoint Designer Gives you a tree view navigation which we can use to browse the files and edit/save.

**Update**

You can use some registry tweak so that you can open files using your favourite editor from Internet Explorer itself.

Also you can associate Client Application to open from Internet Explorer. I.E you can set JS file to be opened by Notepad++

http://www.sharepointmaestra.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=37

Comment: Okay, I am not aware of those registry tweaks. Thanks a lot for the hint, will try it soon.

Comment: Vishnu: Check my update on setting default program.